# Como Localizar valores maiores ou menores entre colunas dentro de um data frame no R

Tags: query, r, dataframe

Possuo um data frame `x`, e na coluna de nome `V_de_Busca`, onde o valor for maior que 0, preciso fazer uma busca na coluna `V_Encontrado` e localizar o primeiro valor maior que o procurado seguindo os índices.

Sendo assim, por exemplo, o valor "12", teria que retornar "14" e não "15", pois ele está em uma data anterior a do valor "12" buscado. Outro exemplo o valor "17", teria que retornar o valor de "20", ou o valor "10" teria que retornar "12".

```
x = data.frame(Índice = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
               Data = as.Date(c("2019-01-22", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-10")),
               V_Encontrado = c(10,15,18,14,09,06,12,13,20,22), 
               V_de_Busca = c(0,0,0,12,0,10,0,17,07,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código seguinte calcula o para cada valor de `V_de_Busca` o primeiro valor de `V_Encontrado` maior que esse valor de `V_de_Busca`.

```
x$Maior <- sapply(seq.int(nrow(x)), function(i){
  if(x[i, "V_de_Busca"] == 0){
    0
  } else {
    j <- i + which(x[i:nrow(x), "V_Encontrado"] > x[i, "V_de_Busca"]) - 1
    if(length(j) > 0) x[j[1], "V_Encontrado"] else 0
  }
})

x
#   Índice       Data V_Encontrado V_de_Busca Maior
#1       1 2019-01-22           10          0     0
#2       2 2019-01-21           15          0     0
#3       3 2019-01-20           18          0     0
#4       4 2019-01-18           14         12    14
#5       5 2019-01-17            9          0     0
#6       6 2019-01-16            6         10    12
#7       7 2019-01-15           12          0     0
#8       8 2019-01-14           13         17    20
#9       9 2019-01-11           20          7    20
#10     10 2019-01-10           22          0     0
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado. Resolveu tudo que precisava.